# How to handle a plagiarism report commented by arxiv?

Tags: mathematics, paper-submission, plagiarism, arxiv

I wrote an article in mathematics (number theory) and submitted it in arxiv in January 2020. I did check plagiarism at my institute which was less than 10%. (**Edit:** Why do I check ? Because it is 2016 PhD regulation of our country which says an article or thesis must have plagiarism less than 10% and that is the reason we check every article in university library with Urkund software). I have the certificate of that article provided by the institution. Anyway, arxiv accepted the submission, however few months later arxiv moderators has withdrawn the article citing overlap report:

> submission has been withdrawn by arXiv administrators due to
> inappropriate text reuse from external sources

I am a PhD student and had no deep literature review in that particular field at that time. I was just attacking a question. I was still unable to realise because similar papers do not directly attacked the question that I was trying to solve. Later, I approached some experts in that field and they praised the my results, however they also mentioned that few of my results are *parallel* study by me while the rest are interesting.

Then after 1 year, I had modified the article and vastly changed it and extended it, which again had plagiarism less than 10%. I also gave it a new suitable title. I then submitted it in arxiv at the end of 2021, and it is accepted by arxiv moderators till date. But I think I made a mistake here because I submitted the new version as a different article with different identifier. Though I wanted to replace the old one by new version, but could not replace because the old one was already withdrawn by moderators and there was no option of replacing.

Now the current situation is that, if I search over arxiv or google with the title of the old version article, then it appears in arxiv showing only abstract and the admin message that I included above. And this makes me worry about  the reputation of the new version of the article, as well as reputation of mine. I submitted the new version in a journal and it is under review. But I am thinking  that since the old version was withdrawn by arxiv, it will give wrong impression to the reviewers. If I put my name in any search engine like google, the arxiv link of the old version (only abstract) plus the admin message can be seen there. This is an embarrasing  situation.

Since the 3 linked papers suggested by arxiv software, doesn't have any significant textual overlap (I checked), now I am planning to write the arxiv moderators to merge the new-version in place of the old version, so that it become just one article and the admin message get disappeared.

Is that the appropriate way to handle the situation ?

Thanks

Comment: The percentage of plagariasm doesn't help at all.
If you performed genuine work for the majority of the text, but copied some literature review verbatim, the result would be less than 10% for each algorithm.

Did you check the overlap that was identified by the algorithm?

Comment: @StephanZ., as I mentioned that some experts few results are parallel  to some previous work and some are interesting. I have also checked the similar article of some big mathematicians but i found no direct link with my results

Comment: @MAS StephenZ's question to you went into a different direction. It's not about the paper's content, it's about whether the sentences that are highlighted by the plagiarism checker contain sentence parts that are taken from elsewhere. Even copying a single non-trivial sentence part is already plagiarism unless accompanied with the proper citation marks, also when shuffling parts. As a rule of thumb, never paste information into your paper found in other publications without adding a quotation and quotation marks *immediately*. When writing a non-quotation sentence, always start from scratch.

Comment: @DCTLib, thanks. as far as I remember, I didn't see any full sentence overlap in the old article, however, there might have overlap for 3-4 words at a time. The whole matter still unsolved to me. So better i should write to arxiv moderators

Comment: Is the question out of topic ? Because it is getting downvotes. I think it should have place here

Comment: @MAS I think the question is getting downvotes because you're not giving us all the relevant information. Plagiarism is a *really serious* accusation, and arXiv surely would have told you what sources your submission overlapped with and you'd be able to tell whether their judgement was correct. You're kind of skirting around it, telling us you "as far as I remember" didn't plagiarize and that there were a "few words" of overlap. A parallel study, not doing a very thourough literature review or the fact that you wrote a new article have nothing to do with plagiarism.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden, I have told everything that old version was withdrawn due to the above 'text overlap' message while the modified version is in arxiv since 6 months. What more information can there be ? Some experts said that my question is interesting with some interesting results however few are parallel. While the similar papers directed by arxiv does not have any mathematical similarity rather than texual. All I mentioned above. I also agree plagiarism is serious offense and thats the reason I always check in ou Urkund software.

Comment: For starters, you could explain why you even felt the need to proactively check your own article for plagiarism? I have written quite a few math articles. Checking for plagiarism never occurred to me. You know why? Because I wrote the damn articles! (Paraphrasing, not plagiarizing, Bernie Sanders ;) ).

Comment: @N.I., because our PhD regulation 2016 (in my country) says a thesis can have plagiarism less than 10%. Thus it is a clear instruction by my supervisor that any article before submitting to arxiv must pass through plagiarism checking and our institution provide certificate to that checking.  Thats is why all scholars of our institution a first check plagiarism.  Does this answer your question ? I have at least 10 articles in arxiv and only problem occurred in that single article

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The elephant in the room is whether you indeed committed plagiarism or whether arXiv admins withdrew the article erroneously. I think arXiv is generally quite lenient in detecting plagiarism and will give the author the benefit of the doubt, so the chances of being flagged erroneously seem small. In this case, there is nothing you can do.

Otherwise (if the withdrawal was in error), you can appeal to the moderators to have the flag removed. That process is [described on the arXiv help page](https://arxiv.org/help/overlap), but you will have to explain in detail why arXiv's assessment was in error.

Comment: Thanks. However my new version is in arxiv. So I should write to moderators regarding both old version and new version.

Comment: Yes, thatb is the proper course of action.Write to the mods.